# Pharo ZnClient possible to host more than one server instance?

Tags: pharo

My question is about hosting multiple ZnServers in Pharo:

I put together an app that is mapped to default delegate. I also want to be able to generate and serve files for download so I thought I would also host a file serve with `ZnStaticFileServerDelegate` class. I tried as so:

```
| a b |
a := ZnServer new.
a := ZnServer startOn: 80.
a delegate: (  
ZnStaticFileServerDelegate new
directory: '/var/www' asFileReference;
prefixFromString: 'files';
yourself).
```

along with:

```
b := ZnServer new.
b := ZnServer startOn: 80.
b default delegate map: #display to: WebRedirect new.
```

But when I try to run both, I get the error mess that ZnStaticFileServerDelegate #doesNotUnderstand default delegate map.

Is there any way to host both on the same image?

Comment: as a temporary fix I just ran two images, one for each server.